# Subscribe and publish velocity

Tags: ros, node, velocity, topic, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a code where I want to see the linear velocity of a powered wheelchair and then publish linear velocity to it.
An example of the code is:

```
ros::Publisher vel_pub_=n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
if(vel.linear.x > 1.8){
    vel.linear.x = 1.8;
    vel_pub_.publish(vel);}
```

--**UPDATE**--

To subscribe to the cmd_vel topic I do:

```
ros::Subscriber vel_sub = n.subscribe("cmd_vel", 0, velCallback);
```

My question is... What do I insert in the velCallback function? What does it contain? What should the header of the function be?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189543/subscribe-and-publish-velocity/) by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to synchronize the data and use one callback for both of the topics, have a look at the [message_filter tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters).

Edit:

The callback should look something like this (no guarantee that this works though, beware of typos):

```
void velCallback(geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& vel) {
 //Since vel is a const pointer you cannot edit the values inside but have to use the copy new_vel.
 geometry_msgs::Twist new_vel = *vel; 
 if(vel->linear.x > 1.8) {
    new_vel.linear.x = 1.8; 
    vel_pub_.publish(new_vel);
  }
}
```

Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) to see how subscribers and publishers work.

I would also suggest to have a queue size of at least 1: `ros::Subscriber vel_sub = n.subscribe("cmd_vel", 1, velCallback);`

Edit2:

For the case you mentioned in the comments something like this could work (not tested, beware of typos):

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

ros::Publisher pub;

void velCallback(geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& vel)
{
   geometry_msgs::Twist new_vel = *vel;
   if (vel->linear.x > 1.8) {
     new_vel.linear.x = 1.8;
   }
   pub.publish(new_vel);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
ros::NodeHandle n;

pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 10);
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("my_cmd_vel", 10, velCallback);

ros::spin();

return 0;
}
```

You only have to make sure that the node publishing the original `cmd_vel` values publishes to `my_cmd_vel` now which you can achieve via [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) the topic in the launch file. The node I posted above will take that value and pass it on to `cmd_vel` or change the linear speed if necessary and then pass it on to `cmd_vel`.

Since the callback is running in a different [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) than your main function you cannot rely on always having a value for your `linear_actual` in the main function. So do whatever you need to do with the actual values in the callback. In this easy example this is good enough.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-13**:
Hi @Chrissi, do you this this will work?

```
void velCallback (const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& vel_msg) {

ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher vel_pub_=n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
geometry_msgs::Twist vel;

linear_actual=vel_msg->linear.x;
angular_actual=vel_msg->angular.z;
}
```

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-13**:
What I do in the code I inserted in the comment above is to update linear and angular velocity to the current velocities!

Then, in main function I do:

```
if(linear_actual > 1.8){
    vel.linear.x = 1.8;
    vel_pub_.publish(vel);}
```

Is this ok?

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-08-13**:
I wouldn't create the publisher in the callback because then the publisher will be created when ever a new message arrives, this is unnecessary. Even though a kitten dies every time you use global variable, I would make it a global variable.
The thing with the cmd_vel is, that still both messages will reach the robot, so the one with linear.x > 1.8 and your new one and the robot will not know what to do and start stuttering. You have to [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) the output of whatever publishes the cmd_vel in the first place to a new topic and listen to that. Then you pass on every message you get to cmd_vel and change it where necessary.

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-13**:
Sorry, my bad! I forgot to delete the publisher in the code!

```
void velCallback (const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& vel_msg) {

linear_actual=vel_msg->linear.x;
angular_actual=vel_msg->angular.z;
}
```

The code is just like this.. I just updates the current velocity!

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-13**:
The rest of the code, the comparison to see it its greater that 1.8 I need to have in the main, because in the real code I have, it isn't so simple! So I really need to do this comparison inside main!

Is it ok this time?

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-08-13**:
You have to make sure that callback is not writing to the variable while you are trying to read it. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882809/boost-mutex-scoped-lock) on how to use boost scoped lock

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-13**:
This updates at a rate of 40Hz... I will be a matter of milliseconds, I am assuming that shouldn't be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes you can subscribe two or more topics in one node there is example of subscribing two laser scanner and merge the data then publish the msg:

```
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"

sensor_msgs::LaserScan downlaser;
ros::Publisher *pub;
bool new_downlaser=false;

void down_laser(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan& msg)
{
    new_downlaser=true;
    downlaser=msg;
}




void up_laser(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan& msg)
{
    sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan;
    scan=downlaser;
    if(new_downlaser)
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard both");

        for(int i=0;i<msg.ranges.size();i++)
        {
            if(downlaser.ranges[i]<msg.ranges[i])
                scan.ranges.at(i)=downlaser.ranges[i];
            else
                scan.ranges.at(i)=msg.ranges[i];
        }
    }
    pub->publish(scan);
}





int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "scan_macher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;



    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("upscan", 10, up_laser);
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = nh.subscribe("downscan", 10, down_laser);


    pub=new ros::Publisher(nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan",10));
    ros::spin();
    return 0;


}
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-10**:
Hi @hamid, my concern now is, what do I insert in the callback function? This verification I do:

```
if(vel.linear.x > 1.8){
    vel.linear.x = 1.8;
    vel_pub_.publish(vel);}
```

I have to do it in the main, along with the rest of my code... so what do I put in the callback function?